# Iterate a Leaflet marker cluster group and update the titles of the markers

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer

```
       Self.companyMarkersClusterGroup.eachLayer(function(layer){
            const companyData = layer.options.companyData;

            layer.title = GetCompanyMapMarkerTitle(companyData);  
          });
```

I am trying to iterate over all markers in a Leaflet [marker cluster group](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) and update their titles.

The code above does not seem to work. What am I doing wrongly?

Could it be that the inner loop variable `layer` is a local deep copy from the marker, so that updating it does not update the marker? If so, how do I update the marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "title", you mean the native tooltip / [`title` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker-title) on Marker icon that comes when you instantiate the Marker like that:

```js
L.marker(latLng, {
  title: "marker icon native tooltip"
});
```

...then you need to update the Marker *options* title, as well as fiddle with its current icon title (if any) to update it immediately (in case the icon is currently displayed on map):

```js
const newTitle = "new title content";
layer.options.title = newTitle;
const icon = layer.getElement();
if (icon) {
  icon.title = newTitle;
}
```

Note that if the native tooltip is currently displayed (i.e. if the user mouse is currently hovering the icon), the browser may not update the content before it disappears and reappears again.

Comment: Thanks for that !  A few points. I did not initialize the title, as it will always be set later. WRT your note, I would suggest using ` L.DomEvent.on(button, 'mouseover', this._mouseover, this);` and defining `mouseover : function ()`.

Comment: Also, `icon` was never true for my markers. Not that matters; this code works, but I just though that I would point it out for future readers. Thanks again :-)